# How to develop with both Assembly and C/C++ on FASM?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, operating-system, fasm

So, I am developing an OS and for now I've been only writing code in assembly. I wish to continue making it with C/C++.
The compiler/editor I use is FASM (for Windows). I've tried using MinGW with it, but it gives error when linking fasm's .o file.
How can I continue developing with both Assembly and C/C++?
Also, I've searched on the Internet a lot, but I didn't find a solution.

Edit:
this is the make batch file i'm using:

```
cls
echo off

fasm.exe los.asm losasm.o
pause
cls
"C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" -nostdlib  los.cpp -o loscpp.o
pause
cls
"C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" -o "C:\Users\helder\Desktop\Lemperyum OperativeSystem I\los" -o -nostdlib losasm.o loscpp.o
pause
cls

pause
```

Comment: What sorts of errors?

Comment: @user3553031 File not recognized.

Comment: Aside: Any reason you're not using `make` or something like it for builds? (GNU Make is available as part of mingw, probably already installed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FASM is biased toward generating executable files directly as its output, the default being "flat binary output" (see [manual](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual)).  To create object files, you have to use one of the command line options

- `format COFF`   or
- `format ELF`

Which you choose depends on the other tools.  Offhand, I am not sure what type of file MinGW outputs.